# How to serialize enums to XML text

Tags: c#, xml, enums

I have currently next field in my serilizable class:

```
[DataMember]
[XmlElement(DataType = "string")]
public string Type {get;set;}
```

And in XML it is serilized like:

```
<Type>Type1</Type>
<Type>Type2</Type>
```

and so on...

I want it to be enum

```
public enum MyType
{
Type1,
Type2,
...
}
```

But how can I serialize it same way as simple string? Is it even possible?

Comment: I don't understand your question, it is being serialized using the enum name, maybe you could give an example of your desired outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
  public enum EmployeeStatus
    {
       [XmlEnum(Name = "Single")]
       One,
       [XmlEnum(Name = "Double")]
       Two,
       [XmlEnum(Name = "Triple")]
       Three
    }
```

more about visit [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlenumattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can decorate your `enum` element with [XmlEnum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlenumattribute.aspx):

```
public enum MyType
{
    [XmlEnum(Name="Type1")]
    Type1,
    [XmlEnum(Name="Type2")]
    Type2,
    ...
}
```

Give proper `Name` to make it appear in the XML the way you want.